# Coordinates of every node in a binary tree?

Tags: javascript, tree, coordinates, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I have the following function for calculating coordinates for every node in a binary tree.

```
//x & y parameters should be untouched
//root assumed to be 0,0
function nodeCoordinates(node, x, y)
{

    if (x === undefined && y === undefined ) {x = 0; y = 0;}
    if (!node) {return;}

    console.log("Node: " + node.value + " x: " + x + " y: " + y);
    nodeCoordinates(node.left, --x, --y);
    nodeCoordinates(node.right, x+=2, y--);

}
```

Node and Tree(BST):

```
//Nodes for BST
function Node(val) {
    this.value = val;
    this.left = null;
    this.right = null;
}

//Binary Search Tree
function BST() {

    this.root = null;

}
```

For x, it should decrement if it goes left.  increment if it goes right.

For y, it should decrement as it goes down a level.

Example test code and output:

```
my_BST.insert(50);
my_BST.insert(60);
my_BST.insert(55);
my_BST.insert(20);
my_BST.insert(70);
my_BST.insert(80);
my_BST.insert(10);
my_BST.insert(30);
my_BST.insert(65);
nodeCoordinates(my_BST.root);
```

- Node: 50 x: 0 y: 0
- Node: 20 x: -1 y: -1
- Node: 10 x: -2 y: -2
- Node: 30 x: 0 y: -2
- Node: 60 x: 1 y: -1
- Node: 55 x: 0 y: -2
- Node: 70 x: 2 y: -2
- Node: 65 x: 1 y: -3
- Node: 80 x: 3 y: -3

The output is correct but this was the result of fiddling with how the parameters are passed in with recursion and it feels unintuitive.  Can someone help me clarify what's going on?  Is there a more intuitive way to go about this?

Comment: i have a problem with your strange use of incrementers as parameters.

Comment: Ehh.  It's not the most conventional way to save values, but it's pretty convenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the parameter handling, without using assignment or increment operators.

```
function nodeCoordinates(node, x, y) {
    x = x || 0;
    y = y || 0;
    if (!node) {
        return;
    }
    console.log("Node: " + node.value + " x: " + x + " y: " + y);
    nodeCoordinates(node.left, x - 1, y - 1);
    nodeCoordinates(node.right, x + 1, y - 1);
}
```

Basically `y` is the level of the tree, with goes below zero.

`x` is misleading, because nodes can have the same *"coordinates"*, like

> ```
> Node: 30 x: 0 y: -2
> Node: 55 x: 0 y: -2
> ```

Comment: just a suggestion, you could address every node with a numerical representation when numbering each node from the beginning with zero and  increment for each node on the same level first and then go to the next level. for example level 0 is 0, level 1 has node number 1 and 2, level 2 has 3, 4, 5, 6, snd so on.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Is there a reason why there is a difference in behavior regarding increments/decrements compared to operations with literals in this case?  Also, yes it does look like I have to redefine what x is, perhaps going along with your suggestion.